# LS command for torrent files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bittorrent

I have a directory full of torrent files,and i have to download all of them; But the problem is i have disk limit in my remote server,and file sizes are vary(100MB~8GB) and if i add all of torrent files ,none of them would be download completely;So i need a command to list all my torrents and the size of them , to be selected and add to download list later .

NOTE: REMOTE SERVER -> **LINUX_UBUNTU_9.10** // SSH

So i need a command like

```
torrentls
```

That output somethings like:

```
file1.torrent     1111MB
file2.torrent     222MB
file3.torrent     3333MB
file4.torrent     444MB
file5.torrent     5555MB
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay. Second go. :)
TorrentInfo python script (usually you have python installed on a linux distro):
http://vrai.net/project.php?project=torrentinfo
`torrentinfo *.torrent | grep size`
Or just: `torrentinfo *.torrent` (as the page shows)

Comment: Edited the answer, sorry for the misunderstanding. ^^"

Answer (score 0):

you can use `du -sk *.torrent`